# How to get client response headers with PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, nginx

guys. I'm building a crypto coin mining pool, the original pool was based off of Node.JS. Which Node.JS is not up to the fast pace of the mining pool. So I was building the pool to run in NGINX and PHP. How the miner works, it interacts with the pool API. The miner has some important information in headers, such as miner type, version, capacity, and etc. Is there a way to get the headers with PHP preferably, if not can it be done with JavaScript. Thanks. :)

With Node.JS I was using: `req.headers`

This is what I have tried in PHP:

```
$_SERVER["USER"] = www-data
$_SERVER["HOME"] = /var/www
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = 10.10.31.95
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = Jetty/9.4.2.v20170220
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] = gzip
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] = 200
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] = _
$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] = 80
$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] = 10.10.31.95
$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"] = 57488
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = 10.10.30.0
$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = nginx/1.10.3
$_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"] = CGI/1.1
$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] = http
$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] = HTTP/1.1
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = /var/www/html
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"] = /burst.php
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = /burst?requestType=getMiningInfo
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] = /burst.php
$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"] = 
$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] = 
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] = GET
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = requestType=getMiningInfo
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = /var/www/html/burst.php
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = 
$_SERVER["FCGI_ROLE"] = RESPONDER
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = 
$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] = 1507362021.8898
$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] = 1507362021
```

Comment: Any header in particular you need? It should just be in the corresponding `$_SERVER[HTTP_HEADER_NAME]` field

Comment: You can see the headers  that came in your case `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = 10.10.31.95`, 
`$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = Jetty/9.4.2.v20170220`, 
`$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] = gzip`

Comment: echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HEADER_NAME"]; Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HEADER_NAME in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
function get_contents() {
  file_get_contents("http://example.com");
  var_dump($http_response_header);
}
get_contents();
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Out put.

```
array(13) {
[0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" 
[1]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes" 
[2]=> string(29) "Cache-Control: max-age=604800" 
[3]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" 
[4]=> string(35) "Date: Sat, 07 Oct 2017 23:51:45 GMT" 
[5]=> string(22) "Etag: "359670651+gzip"" 
[6]=> string(38) "Expires: Sat, 14 Oct 2017 23:51:45 GMT" 
[7]=> string(44) "Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT" 
[8]=> string(22) "Server: ECS (lga/1386)" 
[9]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding" 
[10]=> string(12) "X-Cache: HIT" 
[11]=> string(20) "Content-Length: 1270" 
[12]=> string(17) "Connection: close" 
}
```